# Dequeue Gutenburg Block Library CSS ('wp-block-library') in Admin

Tags: block-editor, wp-enqueue-script

I am working on removing the default Gutenberg block library stylesheet and replacing it with custom pared-down styles. I do not want the original stylesheet to load on either the front or back end, as it means I'd need to add unnecessary bulk to the custom styles in order to override styles in the default stylesheet.

I've successfully dequeued the styles from the front end using the standard in a `wp_enqueue_scripts` action:

```
function test_function(){
    wp_dequeue_style('wp-block-library');
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'test_function' );
```

However, this does not dequeue the styles from the block editor. I have tried dequeuing from an `admin_init` action as well, and that also does not remove the styles from the block editor.

Is it possible to dequeue this stylesheet from *both* the front-end and the admin block editor?

Comment: you're using the frontend specific enqueue scripts hook, you should use the admin area specific hook instead, though there's probably a better more official way to do this than dequeuing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course, five minutes after I post the question, I find a solution:
Using

`wp_deregister_style('wp-block-library')`

(instead of `wp_dequeue_style('wp-block-library')`) works for the block editor. It worked in either an `admin_init` or an `admin_enqueue_scripts` action.